# Fullcalendar timeline week view the event end is not working

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

This is my calendar init code,using V5.8.0

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById(id);

calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'today prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'resourceTimelineWeek'
  },
  aspectRatio: 1.8,
  initialView: options.defaultView || 'resourceTimelineWeek',
  views: {
      resourceTimelineWeek: {
    slotDuration: '12:00',
    slotLabelInterval: '12:00',
    slotLabelFormat: ['dddd', 'A']
      }
  },
  resourceGroupField: options.resourceGroupField,
  resources: options.resources
 });
```

And this is my event data

```
var test = [
            {
                "id":123,
                "resourceId":"jo_1",
                "start":"2000-05-02T00:00:00",
                "end":"2000-05-04T23:00:00",
                "title":"DJO",
                "backgroundColor": "white",
                "textColor": "black",
                "borderColor": "#cecede"
            }
            ];
```

when the event add to the calendar,the end of the event seems not working,what should I change?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the end of the event seems not working" ?

Comment: @EscOfficial if you look at the start and end dates of the event in the data, and then compare that with the time period the event appears to cover in the picture, then you can clearly see what is meant.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this problem with standard fullCalendar 5.8 and the data you've provided - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/oNWedvg . I can only guess that perhaps some CSS from your page is interfering with it somehow, or that your event data isn't precisely as you've reported. If you need further assistance, please update your question to provide a [mre] which will demonstrate the issue when the code and data is used. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all,I found the issue,after remove the including of scheduler.min.css,its working.